# <a> tag with position:relative and auto margins won't change with viewport change

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `<a>` tag in a `<div>`. I have set its width to be less than its parent element width, and its `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto`. I have applied similar stylings to other sibling elements in the `<div>` which have the desired behavior of moving around when I change the viewport in relation to the left and right margins. However I have this single `<a>` which doesn't seem to be setting its `margin-left` and `margin-right` based on changes to the viewport.

Here is the fiddle:

the `<a>` is the only `<a>` wrapping the only `<button>`

https://jsfiddle.net/6k0o4zps/4/

Comment: Do you mean the <a> around the apply now button?

Comment: @sdcr yes, sorry I will change the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get rid of `left:150px`, and also make the `<a>` as block level.

And you only need to target `.front-page-calculator a` in the case.

https://jsfiddle.net/6k0o4zps/11/

```
.front-page-calculator a {
  position: relative;
  /* left: 150px; */
  top: -140px;
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block; /*added*/
}
```

Comment: what is your rationale for removing the `left`. Ah I understand, to center the item.

Comment: Well I really don't want to center *per se*, but rather place it in a responsive fashion. Is this bad practice to set auto margins *and* set the left value?

Comment: because it's set to `position:relative`, the `left` surely affects the position.

Comment: I currently do it frequently on my current project, as I have never learned another way to get the same behavior.

Comment: it is responsive with `margin: auto` set, just don't use relative with left or right position.

Answer (score 2):

Add `display:block;` to the anchor element. In your code it is set to `inline`

Here is a nice article focusing on effects of display:inline in detail. http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

And if you want the element to be at the center of the viewport remove left `left: 150px;`